# How to connect to external proxy on port 3459 from GCP VM Instance?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have a proxy server which accepts connections on port 3459. When I am trying to connect to it from my local computer, I am able to connect. To test I ran this command in terminal:

`curl --proxy http://proxy_url:3459 --proxy-user user:password -L icanhazip.com`

When I tried to run the same in a GCP Compute Engine VM instance which lies in a non-default VPC (named `testing-vpc`), I'm unable to connect to the proxy. 
I have created a firewall rule to open port 3459 by following command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create proxy-allow-egress-port3459 \
  --network testing-vpc \
  --action allow \
  --direction egress \
  --rules tcp:3459 \
  --destination-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 \
  --priority 10 \
  --target-tags testing-proxy
```

and attached the tag `testing-proxy` in my instance. Still, its not working. Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: - Every VPC network has two [implied firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) which permit outgoing connections and block incoming connections (However, GCP firewall rules are [stateful](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall), it allows bidirectional communication once a session is established). Creating a firewall rule to allow outgoing traffic isn’t required unless outbound access is restricted by a higher priority firewall rule.

Comment: Just to ensure that the configuration were correctly done, could check the following:                                   
- Have you already checked if traffic from the VM Instance is allowed on the external proxy server on port 3459?
- Is the VM instance able to send traffic to any other external hosts on the Internet? 

Also is it possible to share a basic diagram showing the expected network path from the VM instance to the proxy server (showing the NAT gateway instance and any other components in between the source and destination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an egress (--direction egress) rule, whereas you need an ingress rule to permit connections inbound destined to the GCE instance.

Comment: What is the network connectivity between GCP and the external proxy?  Is it accessible over the Internet or through VPN/Interconnect?

Comment: It is accessible over the internet as a normal HTTPS proxy. I am using squid proxy server. I am able to use it on my local computer.

Comment: Does your GCP have an external IP address assigned or is using Cloud NAT?

Comment: The GCP instance which lies inside testing-vpc from which I am trying to connect to the proxy is using a NAT server to connect. While the proxy server is a normal instance having an external IP.

Comment: I'm confused; is the proxy you are trying to connect to running inside GCP?  Assuming it is _not_, can you connect to the proxy from your "NAT server"?

Comment: Let's suppose the proxy server is somewhere else in the internet listening on port 3459 which I am able to connect from my laptop. When I try to connect to it from my NAT server or any other instance inside the subnet, it is unable to do so. I tried to open the port using ingress as well as egress. still, it didn't work.

Comment: The default VPC firewall allows all egress traffic, so you shouldn't need a rule unless you've modified the default behavior.

Did you make any changes to the default (0/0) route in the VPC?

Can you connect to other destinations on the Internet from the same instance(s)?

Comment: Apparently, the default settings were changed and that's why it was not working. I added an ingress allow on the port in the firewall as well as had to set up routes for the instance. It is working now. Thank you for your help :)